# How to set manually scale factor of receive window size in windows8? (Window Scaling - RFC 1323)

Tags: windows, networking

My internet download/upload speed is 6.0/0.6 Mbps. One day, when only I was using network bandwidth on LAN, I started downloading a large file from YouTube by using [IDM](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/).

Initially, I easily use all of the bandwidth that I have. But after a few minutes of downloading, the bandwidth used is decreased by nearly a half. And then after a few minutes, it reaches max bandwidth again. After some research on RFC 1323, I know that the culprit of this phenomenon is scale factor.

So, does anyone know the way to adjust this scale factor to a fixed value (in Registry or in config file of software)?